# Android studio 3.1.2 проблемы с прокси Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

Вчера обновил студию до последней версии и сразу после обновления появилась проблема.

```
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.0/gradle-3.1.0.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
```

Раньше все работало хорошо.
настройки в File->Setting->HTTP proxy есть настроены как и раньше.
есть файл gradle.properties там тоже все настроено

`systemProp.http.proxyHost=lmp.corphost.bimbam.jan`

`systemProp.http.proxyPort=1111`

`systemProp.http.proxyUser=a.user`

`systemProp.http.proxyPassword=twerk@1222`

пробовал удалять папку c:/user/.gradle
не помогло проблема остается.
если зайти в File->Setting->HTTP proxy и там нажать Check connection там пишет что все хорошо. но при билде проекта ошибка повторяется

Кто то сталкивался? как решить?

Comment: А у Вас браузер тоже через прокси? В нём эта ссылка открывается?

Comment: @woesss да тоже через прокси,в браузере открывается